# Getting data synchronously from an asynchronous NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nsnotifications

I'm trying to write a method that will operate like this:

```
NSString *responseData = [myAwesomeWrapper getStringfromURL:@"http://spam.com"];
```

Behind the scenes, I want to do the request asynchronously (because I need authentication and HTTPS). The problem is obviously that asynchronous requests require delegate callbacks using didReceiveResponse. That prevents me from writing the tidy method I have in mind.

While I understand this approach, I'm sick of the complicating factor it's creating when I need to make several different requests and access the data directly from the same controller. Inventing ways to capture the data without conflicting with existing calls is growing old.

I've read about possibly using NSNotificationCenter to imitate this, but the examples I've read don't reveal an obvious way to make this work.

Is my C# brain asking for too much?

*Full disclosure: I'm really new at Objective-C/Cocoa-Touch.  Go easy on me. :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Comment: I was reading over the docs tonight and decided it had the same limitation. Can you provide any more information? (I'll start investigating this angle though)

Comment: Or...did you simply mean I could do synchronous requests with auth?

Comment: Yeah have a look at the how to use section, down the middle they have a few examples of multiple async request and how to handle them with NSOperationQueue. The cool thing about ASIHTTPRequest is that you can create custom selectors to be called for each of your connections, or pass custom info in a NSDictionary with each of your conenctions to make it easy to identify which is which upon completion. Link is here http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Ah, that does sound more useful.  I'll investigate and give you credit if this is the direction I end up going :)

Comment: Thank you, sir. Very flexible library!